# How to read hdfs kafka data using pyspark?

Tags: java, python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read data stored to HDFS acquired through Kafka and SparkStreaming.

I am using a Java app which saves some arbitrary data using JavaRDD.saveAsTextFile method to Hadoop HDFS. Basicaly like this:

```
kafkaStreams.get(i).foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecordJavaRDD) throws Exception {
                        consumerRecordJavaRDD.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/abcd_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            });
```

A textfile lines are pushed through Kafka. The data is saved and I can see it in default hadoop browser at *localhost:50070*.

Then, in a pyspark app I am trying to read the data using sparkContext.textFile.

The problem is the data I read (either with python or "by hand" at *localhost:50070*) also contain metadata. So every line is as follows (one long string):

*"ConsumerRecord(topic = abcdef, partition = 0, offset = 3, CreateTime = 123456789, checksum = 987654321, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 28, key = null, value = aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee)"*

I guess there is no sense reading the data as it is and then splitting and parsing the long string to just get the "value" contents is not the best idea.

How should I address this problem, then? Is it possible to read the "value" field only? Or is the problem in the saving itself?

Comment: Saving the data like that makes it almost impossible for any downstream process to use the data without some pre-processing. I highly suggest that you parse the data prior to writing it to HDFS. If you only want to read a single "column" of the data then I suggest saving your data to HDFS in a columnar format, like parquet. If you save a Kafka stream as textFile then you are almost guaranteed to have to read in the data as a string and parse for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No, in the end I would like to save a pretty large .csv files with 20+ columns.

Comment: You'd be much better off using Avro or Parquet, or at the very least JSON. Plaintext is just bad to query against... If you use Confluent's Kafka HDFS Connector, you get Hive Integration out of the box. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks cricket_007, we will indeed use Parquet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

As mentioned in comments under the original post, I saved the data in parquet file format which is column oriented and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you are doing this in the wrong order. I would strongly recommend that you consume data from Kafka directly in your pyspark application. 
You can write the Kafka topic to HDFS *as well* if you want to (remember, Kafka persists data, so when you read it in pyspark will not change what gets written to HDFS from the same topic).

Coupling your PySpark to HDFS when the data is already in Kafka doesn't make sense.

Here's a [simple example](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2017/01/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-with-python-and-kafka/) of consuming data from Kafka in pyspark directly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will definitely think about changing our application architecture. However my problem was something a bit different.